# The stream or file .../logs/laravel.log could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied. Different users need to write logs

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, permissions, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 and everyday I have the same problem on my Laravel 5.5 application:

```
"The stream or file "myapp/storage/logs/laravel-date.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied"
```

And I see a lot of people have had the same issue, and the fix is usually changing permissions and ownership.

My problem is that actually two different users need access to create and write logs: ubuntu (I'm using AWS) and www-data (Apache user).

So if I change ownership to www-data whenever I try to run an artisan command I get the error, and if I change it to ubuntu I get the same issue whenever apache wants to log an error or something.

I have tried to make ubuntu part of the www-data group but that doesn't seem to fix the issue, since whenever a new log file is created with the following permissions

```
-rw-rw-r-
```

Which I think it's what gives me the issue.

So, any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just change the file permission to `777` with `chmod`.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra 777 is a dangerous permission anyday

Comment: I think group permission might be the solution

Comment: Just add both users to a group and then give the group write permission.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, I don't know why but it didn't work. I'm still having the same issue. @Joe

Comment: I wasn't able to figure it out. For anyone interested, I updated Laravel to 5.6 to fix the problem.